# Firebase Firestore: How to check if the document exists before writing data?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check if the document actually exists in the path before uploading data. If not, it will set a new document to the path. If yes, it will just update the data.

Couldn't find a way to do this in the documentation. What will be the best way to do this? Here is what I think will look similar. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
const ref=firebase.firestore().collection('posts').doc('post_id');
if (!ref.exists) {
     firebase.firestore().collection('posts').doc('post_id').set(data);
}
else {
     ref.update(data);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) method **with the [`merge`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SetOptions#optional-merge) option** is what you are looking for:

If the document does not exist, "it will set a new document to the path", if it exists "it will just update the data".

You have to do as follows:

```
const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('posts').doc('post_id');
ref.set(
  {foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo'},
  {merge: true}
);
```